# Typewriter effect in JS (can't pass my string to the typewriter function)

Tags: javascript, function

Currently working on the UI for the first time and I seem to be stuck.

**Here's what I'm trying to achieve:** text1 is typed out once the page is loaded (with the typewriter effect). Then, when the user clicks a button, text1 immediately disappears and text2 begins to be typed out instead.

**My function** *(in my HTML I have a paragraph with id="demo")*

```js
function typeWriter(text,speed) {
  for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
typeWriter("Lorem impsum", 50);
```

**The problem is** that I cannot figure out how to pass my string in the function. The code above returns an error:

> "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'text.length')".

What could I do about that? How can I get the length if I don't want to have some "fixed" string, since I need to pass in 2 different texts, depending on the events?

Comment: The problem is `setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);`, which won't pass any arguments into its callback ( `typeWriter`)

Answer (score 0):

Your error : "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'text.length')".
is caused when you code reached `text.length` because text is `undefined`. Now in first iteration it is correct, but after your `setTimeout`, the callback `typeWriter` does not have any params.

If you want to pass params to a [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) callback, this is the way:

```
setTimeout(functionRef, delay, param1, param2, /* ... ,*/ paramN)
```

Now, you can add that but i believe you do not even need a for loop. Because then in every iteration you will have `n` calls to setTimeout. And every time the callback function itself will call setTimeout.

Doing minor changes to your code, can fix this:

```js
function typeWriter(text,speed,char) {
    if(char < text.length){
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += text.charAt(char);
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed,text,speed,char+1);    
    }
}
typeWriter("Lorem impsum", 50,0);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

In the above sample i am keeping track of the character by passing an index and calling `setTimeout` exactly once every time.